# output shiny app object details in UI

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app has a large cached object it is loading on startup, using readRDS(), that is leveraged in shinyServer() processing to populate shinyUI() defined textOutput().

Is there some trick to populating textOutput UI that says "loading cache object . . . " just before the readRDS() call and changes it to saying "loaded cache object of size, object.size(cacheLoadedObject)" once it has finished loading?

The reason this bit of UI behavior matters is the app input boxes will accept input prior to that object being loaded from disk but they are essentially not functional until it is as the reactive() and renderText() textOutput updates they trigger can't be calculated until that cached object is loaded.

Looked at "shiny app loading UI" hits and didn't find anything on this scenario.

Comment: just a hint (i dont have time to really investigate) - try to use reactive values: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson4/

Comment: @xhudik thanks for response.  Yes i'm currently using reactive() generated function that i pass to a renderText() call whose output is assigned to output$verbatimTextOutputBoxId.   Issue was that i wanted a way to give users some sense that work was happening prior to giving them ability to enter values in inputText controls where next step is dependent on rds cache file having been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the shiny busy indicator to show some text while the object is loading. You may find the following links interesting:

[shiny app busy indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004302/shiny-app-busy-indicator)

http://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#busy-indicator

In addition you could hide/disable the input fields (using shinyjs) on loading and enabling them when loading is finished. See here for more information:

[Disable textInput based on radio button selection on Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831527/disable-textinput-based-on-radio-button-selection-on-shiny)

https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/disabled.html